# Search post overlapping dates - meta_query with meta_key

Tags: post-meta, meta-query

I'm having a search form for rentals that search locations available according to a date range.

For now, I store all reserved dates for each posts as post_meta. For exemple ;

**post_id: 231** post_meta : location_reservation_start : 2022-09-02

**post_id: 231** post_meta : location_reservation_end : 2022-09-08

**post_id: 231** post_meta : location_reservation_start : 2022-10-02

**post_id: 231** post_meta : location_reservation_end : 2022-09-02

(multiple meta_key for the same post)

There is the query :

```
        $start_date = $dates[0] ;
        $end_date = $dates[1] ;     
        $date_query[] = array(
            'key'     => 'location_reservation_start',
            'value' =>  array($start_date , $end_date ) ,
            'compare' => 'NOT BETWEEN',
            'type'    => 'DATE'
        ) ;
        $date_query[] = array(
            'key'     => 'location_reservation_end',
            'value' =>  array($start_date , $end_date ) ,
            'compare' => 'NOT BETWEEN',
            'type'    => 'DATE'
        ) ;
        array_push($meta_query, $date_query );
```

This code work if there's only one post_meta for post. As long as the post have multiple same meta_key, the NOT BETWEEN doesn't seem to work.

There is a way to make it work like that or should I store the reservation dates in a post_meta serialized as an array?

Thanks

Comment: `NOT` style queries are _extremely_ expensive, even if you get this working it won't scale as your site grows, and there's a very high chance you won't be able to handle more than one or two concurrent users on that page. You also need to store the dates in a MySQL friendly format. You should avoid serialized arrays as that means math and date comparisons will no longer be available to you in `WP_Query`

Comment: What will be the best approach to get results outside the dates range? Should I have another mysql table to store reservation dates?

Comment: instead of getting all dates that are _not_ between A and B, it's much faster to get all dates that end before A and start after B. It results in the same information, but the query is much more efficient. We might understand it's essentially the same thing, but a database can't make the same leap of logic